# Can you find the missing number in this grid?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

Can you find the missing number?

[image]

Comment: What is this from? Be sure to credit the source when posting a puzzle not your own.

Comment: It's from new notification application Okay sure.

Answer (score 2):

> The answer is 2. The second and third column in each row, multiplied together, give the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is 2. In each Row,column ONE is equal to multiple of rest of two columns.

> (C1=C2*C3)
>
> 9=3*3
>
> 6=2*3
>
> 8=4*2

So, Answer 2.

(or)

> (C1/C2 = C3)
>
> 9/3=3
>
> 6/2=3
>
> 8/4=2

Comment: It's probably not a bad idea to 'spoilerize' your answer by prefixing it with `>!`.

Answer (score 0):

Also...

> The 3rd row = 2*(1st row - 2nd row) + 2.
>  So once again, 2.